# How to align a line in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

The documentation of line says that how make a line you need to specify the start X, Y and end X,Y of the line. This can be use but only if the scene is of fixed dimensions. 
Instead of specifying the start X, Y and end X,Y of the line I want to directly specify the length of the line, the orientation of the line and simply position it at the center of the scene using `root.setCenter(line);` I don't think there is any way to specify the start X, Y and end X,Y of the line and then align it at the center of the scene horizontally or vertically. Here is an illustration of what I'm trying to achieve: 
[image: line represent]

So to solve this I'm using a BorderPane as my root and then I want to have a horizontal line and align it using `root.setCenter(lines);` but there is no such way to align a line I could find. How can I make specify this location of the line to be horizontally on a scene by just specifying `Pos.CENTER` like other nodes?

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to achieve (an illustration can help) and post [mre].

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say, "That is if the window is resized those lines can other way around."

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of outcome you want to achieve. An image containing the desired look for 2 different sets of width&height could help very much to clarify this. A `Line` remains in place regardless of the size of the window, unless the parent layout sets the position of the line depending on it's own size (like e.g. `StackPane`).

Comment: @fabian and c0der I have changed the OP for better and simple explanation of the problem.

Comment: If you just want to align a node to the center of the parent, just use `StackPane`. The y coordinates do not matter in that case as long as they're the same. Also only the difference in x coordinates are relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how to do it,  as @Fabian said you need to use StackPane as the root of your scene and specify the start end X and Y and align it with StackPane. Here is the code I used:

```java
    private StackPane root = new StackPane();
    private Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1366, 768);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Line line = new Line(0,100,100,100);
        line.setStrokeWidth(20);

        StackPane.setAlignment(line, Pos.CENTER);
        root.getChildren().add(line);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Test");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

Thanks.